# ggplot2 stat density only for y values

Tags: r, ggplot2, point, density-plot

I'm wondering whether I can manipulate `stat_density2d` to show the density for the x values without considering the y values.
To illustrate:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:40, rep(1:20, 3), 15:40))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y = x)) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill='red',alpha=..level..),geom='polygon', show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Obviously I does't really make sense to plot the sames values against each other, however I'm interested in the density of the plots at a certain value. Therefore I would like to keep y constant (e.g `y = 1`) but still show the same density like so: 
[image]

(In my publication I actually have multiple groups, making this a nice way to plot the group separation even though it is 1D)

Comment: so what you really want is a 1d plot like a histogram or violin plot...

Comment: @qwr Yeaah I would like to have a violin plot however I have to stay consistent with my data representation (for a publication). Since the other figures are made using stat_density I would like to keep the same layout